# Lock a file in hard drive sector from accessing by any process

Tags: windows, hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

I have `C5 Current Pending Sector Count` is `1` on my HDD after writing on it.

I found the file in that bad sector *(a folder hash computing with 7zip just stopped on that file)*.
Then I moved the file to a separate folder in the disk's root *(physically the file was not moved)* and put the correct file in the original folder instead of it.
Also I renamed the extension from `.png` to `.badsector` to prevent reading the file by File Explorer for the thumbnail generating.

However, I think that Windows'a auto-defragmentation may physically move the file *(the sector is still not "bad sector", sometimes I was able to successfully read the file)* and place in that bad sector any other file *(with potential corruption of it)*.

**How to prevent the physical moving of a file by any process** *(for example, by a planned executing of Windows drive optimisation (defragmentation))***?** I want to leave the file in this sector forever in order to no one accesses the bad (pending) sector.

Comment: What's the actual goal here? Why do you want to *preserve* the bad sector?

Comment: What you should do is actually *write* to that sector. If it truly is bad then the drive firmware should remap it with a good sector from its "spare" pool. Obviously those can only happen so many times as the spare sectors are only a small part of the disk, but you should let the disk do it's job.

Comment: To don't allow any process to stuck on reading it, more over to don't allow to write in this sector any other file. Will enabling checkboxes in file's Properties -> Security -> Deny for `SYSTEM` work?

Comment: You were able to replace the file with backup, this is the best scenario ever. Now if you delete the original, the pending sector will eventually be overwritten and either it will be fixed by writing to it, or it will be reallocated. Either way the mechanics will work as designed and you will be able to read from this logical sector again. What surprises me is the claim "sometimes I was able to successfully read the file". I expected the firmware to rewrite or remap the pending sector immediately in such case. Maybe I'm missing something, but still I think keeping the file is futile.

Comment: A few times the file was successfully read then it started to fail again. So, it seems for me that technically the situation, when I successfully write in the sector again, but the sector start to fails again, is possible. Since it just a certain 1 MB file on mostly read-only hdd drive, it's not a problem to just keep the file in some special folder.

Comment: What about other SMART parameters? Is the drive out of spares?

Comment: Okay, I fully understand about the relocation feature, thanks. _An additional comment, feel free do not read (1/2):_  No, the problem SMART value is only one Pending Sector. It's just relatively old disk WD3001FFSX 18k hours, 4k power cycles, 60k start/stop count (I set drives to stop after 6 min inactivity in Power Options). _I just decided to swap 300 GB of data with the other hard drive._ By the way, based on the time in Windows Event Log and Error Log of the device (GSmartControl) the Pending Sector appeared while defragmentation.

Comment: (2/2) After moving the file (and changing its permissions) I rechecked CRC of the recently copied folders, everything is correct. Even after a new defragmentation. Read Error Rate value has back to `0` (It was 13 when I first time checked the SMART, and 120 when I found the problem file). The are no new error entries in the device error log (125 total, the most are `Uncorrectable error in data`, some are `Media is write protected`, every one is about the same LBA).

Answer (score 0):

I have C5 Current Pending Sector Count is 1 on my HDD after writing on it.

> I found the file in that bad sector (a folder hash computing with 7zip just stopped on that file).

This is no proof. You might have discovered another broken sector.

> However, I think that Windows'a auto-defragmentation may physically move the file (the sector is still not "bad sector", sometimes I was able to successfully read the file) and place in that bad sector any other file (with potential corruption of it).

If the sector in question is the pending one as stated in your SMART attributes the auto-defragmentation cannot move the file because it can't read the sector.
If the sector is broken and sometime in the future your operating system issues a write command to the drive containing your bad sector, the firmware of the drive will remap the sector during that write process.

> How to prevent the physical moving of a file by any process (for example, by a planned executing of Windows drive optimisation (defragmentation))? I want to leave the file in this sector forever in order to no one accesses the bad (pending) sector.

That is the wrong solution for an assumed problem. Rewrite the file which content you have stored elsewhere to the location where the unreadable copy of your file is stored. That will remap the sector assuming that the pending sector really belongs to your file. This is a solution that will be handled by the firmware of the drive. This is the preferable one because the following second solution proposed will only last as long as the file system exists.
If you read your SMART parameters before and after that operation you should notice that the pending sector count decreases by one and the reallocated sector count increases by one.

On operating system level you could run the chkdsk command with the /r parameter. In simplified terms that will trigger a search for unreadable sectors that will be marked as bad on file system level.
As FAT and NTFS file systems don't handle sectors directly but rather sets of sectors called "clusters" in reality that command will mark each cluster that contains a broken sector as bad and it won't be used by the file system anymore.